# htaccess rule cannot override previous rule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a bunch of htaccess rule setup on website.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^google73947f9bfca52abe.html$    google73947f9bfca52abe.html [L]
RewriteRule ^page\/(.*)$ index.php?title=page&r=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^media\/(.*)$ index.php?title=page&r=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^admin/$    admin/php [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$    index\.php [L]
RewriteRule ^crons/$    crons/ [L]

#I did this to forward request to directory    
RewriteRule ^sites/$    sites/ [L]

#This  is the rule creating problem
#RewriteRule ^sites/([^.]+)$    sites/$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$   /index.php?title=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm       index\.php\?action=$1 [L]RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$   /index.php?title=$1
```

I want to override every rule for those that start with `site.com/sites` to go the directory instead of going to `index.php` as it configured to do so.

Whenever I go to `site.com/sites` the sites takes me to `site.com/site/?title=sites` but I can still browse it as folder but Whenever I open a html file like lets say `test.html` it takes me directly to index.php on earlier directory as it is suppose to.

How to write rule which lets me browse a directly freely?

Answer (score 0):

Use END flag instead of L flag will absolutely END the Rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure to omit all the rules when the line `sites` is encountered.

Here is your solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(sites) - [L]

#Rest of your rules
```